# Script to remove empty strings for form options in Google forms

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am having major problems in getting rid of empty strings in order to fill in options for a Google Form from a Google Spreadsheets. The rest of the script works perfectly fine but it keeps adding empty options to the form (see image). I have tried the script below but it still does not work. Trying to add "undefined" as an option under the "if" under "ChoicesForQuestions" just gives me one answer instead of the others in that row in the spreadsheet. Please help me fix this.

```
function CreateFormfromSheet() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
 var data = range.getValues();
 var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
 var numberColumns = range.getNumColumns();
 var firstRow = 1;
 var form = FormApp.create(data[0][1]);
 form.setDescription(data[1][1]);
 form.requiresLogin(); 

 for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
  var questionType = data[i][0]; 
  if (questionType==''){
   continue;
   }

else if(questionType=='CHOICE'){
 var currentRow = firstRow+i;
 var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getLastColumn();
 var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (getSheetRange));
 var range_string = 'D' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
 var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(range_string).getValues();

 var choicesForQuestion =[];
 for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
  if (optionsArray[j] !== null && optionsArray[j] !== "") {
    choicesForQuestion.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
    }
  }

form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
.setTitle(data[i][1])
.setHelpText(data[i][2])
.setChoiceValues(choicesForQuestion)
.setRequired(true); 
 }
}
```

[Google Form with empty options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyAXd.png)

[image]

Comment: I have never used google script or forms but... Are you checking the right thing with `optionsArray[j] !== ""`? Should it be `optionsArray[0][j] !== ""`?

Comment: That did it Toni W, that solved the whole problem. I knew it was something small. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by doing what Toni W mentioned in his comment below my text. I needed to add [0] before the [j] in the if statement.

Comment: her* and glad I could help! I actually tried duplicating your project to test it and help you but I couldnt figure out how to get spreadsheets and forms to play together and gave up lol